# Android @HiltWorker Field injection not being initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I have a `Worker` which Injects 2 classes, `UriUtil` and `CameraUtil`. Both classes are being provided by the `AppModule`. Even in other classes which do have inheritance with for example `FileProvider`, or don't inherit any class at all. The vars remain null which, if I'm correct, should be provided by the field injection.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun uriUtil(): UriUtil { return UriUtil() }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun cameraUtil(): CameraUtil { return CameraUtil() }
}
```

My worker then tries to field inject, but they remain null:

```
@HiltWorker
class SendToBackendWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted val context: Context,
    @Assisted val workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
    ...

    @Inject
    lateinit var uriUtil: UriUtil

    @Inject
    lateinit var cameraUtil: CameraUtil

    ...
}
```

As the HiltWorker documentation explained (can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/hilt/work/HiltWorker)), I've updated my `Application` class:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
}
```

My AndroidManifest contains:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        ...
```

Can I perhaps only use field injection in classes which inherit from the ones mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes)?

Comment: Witch version of work do you use?

Comment: @MobinYardim Thanks for your reply, the issue was because I wasn't using @EntryPoint in my code. See code example in my answer below. To answer your question, I'm using `2.7.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. There's some additional code required for 'custom' classes, which do not inherit from the ones mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes).

For example, to fix the @Inject code in my Worker I had to add an `@EntryPoint` notation and provide it an interface:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@EntryPoint
interface BackendWorkerEntryPoint {
  fun uriUtil(): UriUtil
  fun cameraUtil(): CameraUtil
}

private fun hiltEntryPoint(appContext: Context) = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
  appContext,
  BackendWorkerEntryPoint::class.java
)

private fun getCameraUtil(appContext: Context): CameraUtil =
  hiltEntryPoint(appContext).cameraUtil()


private var cameraUtil = getCameraUtil(context)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For workManager library version 2.6.0-alpha01 and above you must add this code to your manifest:

```
<provider
android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
android:exported="false"
tools:node="remove" />
```

read warning in the bottom of [this](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager) page from developers.android.com